# Spinner Class In C# Xamarin Is Not Regonized

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

am using Xamarin using VS and c#,
am trying to get a reference to a spinner I have in the XAML file, but c# is not recognizing Spinner class at all, is there any package or anything to do to change that?

adding code:
XAML:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/ingSpr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"/>
```

c# code

```
Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.ingSpr);
```

error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Tool    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Spinner' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   BackingSolutionApp  C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\APP\BackingSolutionApp\MainActivity.cs   18  Compiler    Active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same error.

[image]

Add reference of `Android.Widget` could fix this.

```
using Android.Widget;
```